# Issue with Standard error handling in vba due to unexplained looping

Tags: vba, ms-access, stored-procedures, error-handling, module

I am following instructions on creating a new VBA procedure in Access.  One of the specifications is to use standard ExitProc-Error handling.  I was a little confused on what that ment but I looked at examples online and previously completed examples supplied as a template, I came up with this:

```
On Error GoTo HandleError
'code that may cause errors

ExitProc:
Exit Function
HandleError:
If FindFolders = False Then
    MsgBox ("Required folders for " & InstrumentName & " not found")
ElseIf FindFolderPaths = False Then
    MsgBox ("Required folder paths for " & InstrumentName & " not found")
End If

MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & " in FindFolderPaths"
Resume ExitProc
End Function
```

findfolders is a boolean variable I marked as false in the procedure to indicate an error and FindFolderPaths is the name of the procedure i am using as a indication of whether the paths where found.  When I run this procedure the following msg boxes appear. I created an error in the folder name to show how the error would be handled :

-Required folders for ICPMS not found

-0 in FindFolderPaths

-Required folders for ICPMS not found

-20 Resume without Error in FindFolderPaths

When I stepped through the procedure step by step it looks like its looping through HandleError twice before going to ExitProc and I can't figure out why.  Also the error message changes during the second loop in HandleError which is strange.

Comment: you dont really need the exit proc handler or do you

Comment: When I take out the 'Resume ExitProc' it works fine and I probably don't need it but that being said I still can't figure out why it makes the handleerror loop before going to ExitProc:

Comment: Do you use `Option Explicit` in your module? If no, are all the variables declared by `Dim`?

Comment: Yes there are variables declared by DIM, is that an issue? but I do use Option Explicit

Comment: I was thinking that your error handler might itself throw another error because of missing variable or type mismatch. Because you essentially have the same error handler, it would jump again to `HandleError`, with a different condition.

Comment: By the way, what type are `FindFolders` and `FindFolderPaths`? They should be `Boolean`, right?

Comment: It's making the loop because you are resuming

Comment: Seems like the first time through there is no actual error, so somehow your code is calling the handler but there is no error to show (hence the Resume throws an actual error). Need to see the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you're "mis-using" the error handler by calling it directly in your code using `Goto HandleError` instead of having it called automatically when an error occurs.

This would explain exactly what you report was output when your code ran:

```
-Required folders for ICPMS not found  'shows regardless of what triggers the handler
-0 in FindFolderPaths                  'err number of zero means there's no error
```

`Resume Exit Proc` then triggers an *actual* error, calling the code a second time

```
-Required folders for ICPMS not found        'not relevant here...
-20 Resume without Error in FindFolderPaths  'an actual error number and message
```

Typically if there's some condition you can test for (such as a missing folder) then you don't need to handle that by calling an error handler - you can show a message from your "regular" code and then just `Exit function`.  Alternatively, raise a custom error using `Err.Raise`, giving it a specific error number and description which you can test for and handle appropriately in your Error Handler.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164019(v=office.10).aspx#odc_tentipsvba_topic3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164019%28v=office.10%29.aspx#odc_tentipsvba_topic3)

Answer (score 1):

Remove Resume ExitProc.  The code will leave the function when it hits End Function.  Also, you need to remove the parentheses when you are calling MsgBox.  Only use parentheses when you are setting something equal to MsgBox.

Comment: thank you for the tip with the MsgBox, I didn't realize there was a difference between the format msgbox("") or msgbox " "

Comment: Those parenthesis were probably causing the strange behavior (in other words, that error is the one that was triggering the 'error loop').